# Geting errors with c++ using opencv on raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, python, opencv, c++

For Face Recognition using raspberry Pi with opencv. I have tried using C++ code which is failing to include the opencv files. Please comment any python code for face recognition using opencv.

Comment: Are you using Python or C++? They are not at all the same and cannot be intermixed.  If you want a C++ solution, please include an example of the code you've tried and the errors you get when you try to compile it.

Comment: RVCS, this question is very broad, and isn't very clear. What have you done, and how is it failing? My crystal ball is currently broken, so if you could share more details, it'd save everyone a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

There's a tutorial in [OpenCV's documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html#face-detection) that looks about right.

> OpenCV already contains many pre-trained classifiers for face, eyes,
>   smile etc. Those XML files are stored in opencv/data/haarcascades/
>   folder.
>
> First we need to load the required XML classifiers. Then load our
>   input image (or video) in grayscale mode.
>
> ```
> import numpy as np
> import cv2
>
> face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
> eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
>
> img = cv2.imread('sachin.jpg')
> gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> ```
>
> Now we find the faces in the image. If faces are found, it returns the
>   positions of detected faces as Rect(x,y,w,h). Once we get these
>   locations, we can create a ROI for the face and apply eye detection on
>   this ROI (since eyes are always on the face !!! ).
>
> ```
> faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
> for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
>     cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
>     roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
>     roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
>     eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
>     for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
>         cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
>
> cv2.imshow('img',img)
> cv2.waitKey(0)
> cv2.destroyAllWindows()
> ```
>
> [image: OpenCV face detection example]